# File with non-english fileName fails to upload on SFTP?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sftp, non-english

I am using the following script to upload to SFTP. It works fine except if the filenames have non-english chars.

```
import pexpect
fileName = raw_input("Enter fileName")
#in the pexpect, send the following
put_string = "put {} /test/{}".format(fileName)
p.sendline(put_string)
```

My observation

```
Actual filename = 法嫁

fileName = \xe6\xb3\x95\xe5\xab\x81

put string = put \xe6\xb3\x95\xe5\xab\x81 /test/\xe6\xb3\x95\xe5\xab\x81
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Does SFTP support this type of PUT ? If no, how to upload non-eng chars file.

Versions

1. python2.7

Note - I have tried storing this as unicode, but same issue happens.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use Python 2.7?

Comment: It is the legacy code I have to work on.

Comment: Sorry about that...

Comment: Try `fileName = unicode(raw_input("Enter filename: ").decode("utf-8"))`. Does that work?

Comment: Also, put a `u` in front of `put_string` like so: `put_string = u"put {} ...`

Comment: A lot of Python 2 code is going to be pretty sketchy when it comes to handling non-ASCII text. That's just the nature of the system, where strings could be encoded in who-knows-what way. It's far easier to reason about in Python 3, and library authors are far more likely to have gotten it right, so porting to modern Python (and getting updated versions of the libraries you're using) might make your task a lot easier.

Comment: @MattDMo No that doesn't work. My put statement is now ```u'put  \u6cd5\u5ac1 /test/\u6cd5\u5ac1'``` which still doesn't work